# toggling between two classes jQuery = works but extra click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<a href="#" class="sort">Sort</a> 


   $(".sort").click(function (event) {
        $(this).toggle(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("sortUp","sortDown");
            }, function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("sortDown","sortUp");
           });
    });
```

it works but I need to click once before it works.
so  - 
**click (nothing happens), click (sortUP), click (sortDown)**

**I would like to remove first click.**

Thank you community for the help !

Comment: Start off with the class being "sortUp" or "sortDown".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont' want to begin with a sortUp or sortDown class, do this:

```
<a href="#" class="sort">Sort</a> 

$(".sort").click(function (event) {            
    if($(this).hasClass("sortUp") || $(this).hasClass("sortDown")){
        $(this).toggleClass("sortUp sortDown");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("sortUp");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you're using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) incorrectly. You appear to want to toggle sortDown and sortUp on each click. That's done with `toggleClass("sortDown sortUp")`.

Secondly, you need your class `.sort` to either have `sortUp` or `sortDown` set in its `class` property when you load the page. e.g. `<a href="#" class="sort sortDown">`. This makes sure you can reason about your code (i.e. it's *always* true that exactly one of `sortUp, sortDown` are set on your `div`).

Thirdly, `$(this).click(function() { /* code */ })` means "when somebody clicks, do `/*code*/`". You've wrapped your

`$(this).click(function() { $(this).toggleClass("sortUp sortDown"); })`

which sets up the click behaviour, in a `$(".sort").click(function () {` which means you are requiring an initial click on "sort" just to start the behaviour.

So the correct version is:

```
<a href="#" class="sort sortDown">Sort</a> 


   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sort").click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("sortUp sortDown");
        });
    });
```

Comment: thank you. for some reason instead of toggling between "sortUp / sortDown" it adds and removes two classes at the same time. //cdn.pbui.us/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js So it's "<a href="#" class="sort sortUp sortDown">

Comment: That sounds like you didn't set sortDown in your <a> tag's initial HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding the click events on the first click, also if you want to switch between `sortUp` and `sortDown` you can simply specify them both. As long as the element starts with one or the other (not both and not neither), it will swap them each time.

```
$(".sort").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('sortUp sortDown');
});
```

You can see this running on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXQBH/).